# How can "everyone" be singular or plural?

Tags: classical-latin, pronouns, plural

I don't understand how *quisque* and *quique* are different. How can a pronoun referring to all people be singular or plural? In which situations would one use either of these?

Comment: FWIW, Gildersleeve and Lodge say the plural of *quisque* is "rare until post-classical times". I'm not sure I've ever seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latin does indeed think about number slightly different than we do in English--or Latin reflects subtleties of reference in a slightly different way. *Quisque* is the indefinite pronoun, masculine nominative singular. *Quique* is the indefinite pronoun, masculine nominative plural. *Quisque* clearly means "every [single] one" or  "each one." *Quique* has the same meaning, but distributed across a group: "every [single] one [of this group]," or "each one [of this group]." Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think I see the distinction -- doesn't "every one" necessarily imply some group? It would be good to cite some examples that show the difference.